# Vue store modify data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have use Vue 2 and data in store are:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        "cnf": {
            "rad": {
                "txf": {
                    "minE": [1000000, 1000000],
                    "maxE": [50000000, 50000000]
                },
                "rxf": {
                    "minE": [1000000, 1000000],
                    "maxE": [50000000, 50000000]
                },
                "filtMod": [0, 0],
                "filtCnf": [-999, -999],
                "pn": ["", ""],
                "sn": ["", ""],
                "fw": ["", ""],
                "side": [1, 1]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In template I need to use (and it is wrong)

```
<input type="number" v-model="state.cnf.rad.txf.minE[0] / 1000" />
```

Where can I modify {{ state.cnf.rad.txf.minE[0] }}? In store or template?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assign in store using v-model. Instead you can use the store methods like so.

**Foo.vue**

```
<input type="number" v-model="num" @input="setNum()" />

data() {
  return {
    num: 0
  }
},
methods: {
  setNum() {
    // num here is passed as a payload in store
    // commit is a built-in vuex method to call store actions
    // setNumMutation is the name of mutation in store
    this.$store.commit('setNumMutation', num);
  }
}
```

**Store**

```
state: {
  "cnf": {
    "rad": {
        "txf": {
            "minE": [1000000, 1000000],
            "maxE": [50000000, 50000000]
        },
        "rxf": {
            "minE": [1000000, 1000000],
            "maxE": [50000000, 50000000]
        },
        "filtMod": [0, 0],
        "filtCnf": [-999, -999],
        "pn": ["", ""],
        "sn": ["", ""],
        "fw": ["", ""],
        "side": [1, 1]
    }
  }
},
mutations: {
  setNumMutation(state, payload) {
    state.cnf.rad.txf.minE[0] = payload / 1000
  }
}
```